# Find Regex pattern to match innermost (first) pattern out of bigger pattern

Tags: python, regex

My test string is like this

```
    sdfsdfs sdfsd
    To(SObj,sfddslfks
    To(SObj,
      abc
    ), 
    abc(_)
    )
    ))
    ), 
    To(SObj,
    Or(
    And(
    Or(
      And(
        abc
        Or(
        DCh=t'3', 
         abc
         ab3
        )
      ), 
    To(SObj,  sfdsd
    sdfdsf
    )
    )
```

note: In real string all parenthesis are balanced

I want to write a regex pattern to remove (or match) only `To(SObj` which contains `DCh` in it.

i.e. From above example, only below needs to be removed or matched

```
To(SObj,
Or(
And(
Or(
  And(
    abc
    Or(
    DCh=t'3', 
     abc
     ab3
    )
  ),
```

But, my pattern `(To\(SObj[\s\S]+DCh[\s\S]+)To\(SObj` matches entire test string

Comment: `(((sdfsdfssdfsdTo(SObj,sfddslfksTo(SObj,abc),abc(_))))),To(SObj,Or(And(Or(And(abcOr(DCh=t'3',abcab3)),To(SObj,sfdsdsdfdsf)))))` is balanced. However, python'r `re` can't match balanced items. It may be possible in their new `regex` module, and if it has some Perl constructs, I could give you a regex.

Comment: Note that if using python's `regex` module, it should support recursion and possessive quantifiers. In that case, match `To(?=\(SObj)(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` then check $1 in a replace callback => copy $1 to a  new string, run this regex on it `DCh` or just use a string function. If it exists, replace with nothing, if it doesn't, return the $1 unchanged.

Comment: Here is an example https://regex101.com/r/NH3egU/1

Comment: thanks @sln, let me try this

Comment: sorry, it didn't work with python module. But @LukStorms answer worked

Comment: For this, it's better to find the index of (To(SObj, and then step through the string char by char, counting the ( and ) until they cancel out. Than you will have the start and end index of the the sub-string.

Comment: @Watt - I'm sorry, I thought you were serious here. Pythons `regex` module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/ does indeed support recursion and possessive quantifiers. So, obviously you didn't try it out because all the constructs are supported. `To(?=\(SObj)(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` maybe in the future you actually will try it out. As it is now, you get nothing relating to anything in a way of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without balancing the brackets :

```
resultstring = re.sub(r'To\(SObj,[^)]*?DCh=[^(]*\),','', inputstring, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/U4KaUf/1)

Comment: Thanks, it works, do you mind writing a small explanation on your pattern to help noobs like me. Basically, if you can explain what is going on here ```[^)]*?DCh=[^(]```

Comment: You could look at the explain plan of the test. But a ^ at the start of a character class means is a negation of it. It then looks for any character that's not in it.

Comment: So [^(]* matches 0 or more characters that are not (

Comment: And because it's [^(]*? it's doing a lazy search. Trying to find as little as possible.

Comment: I figured that before the DCh there are no ) And after it no (